# Login to computer with 2 different passwords

Tags: windows, windows-7, login

I think the title is misleading, but I don't know what it should be...

What I want is a program that allows me to set *another* password for logging into my account after it has been locked.

Now,...

- if I type in my default, Windows-set password, I login normally
- if I type in my *other* password, all the programs that are currently open should close (preferably save, but not necessary) and then login.

Requirements:

- above feature
- free / cheap
- run on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Related question on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/333049/can-i-make-windows-have-multiple-passwords-for-a-single-user

Answer (score 1):

Create an Administrator account with your other password then you can switch to it killing the existing session. I think that is what you are looking for!

On Windows 7 the lock screen only lets the original user or "Administrator" to do anything once the computer is locked then as a safety measure the workspace is protected to prevent lost work, etc. So You can log in as Administrator and kill your existing session then log out of Administrator and log back in as you but it is probably quicker and safer to log in and close the running programs, (gives you a chance to save any work you were doing). Alternatively hit the power button if it is configured to shut down.

It would not be possible for a program to 'run as' the built-in Admin account in this circumstance, precisely because the computer is locked. The only way to do what you are asking on Win7/8 is to replace the lock with your own.